# Qt5 msvc 2010 do not recognize auto (c++11)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile my old Qt project on another system: Windows XP, Qt5, msvc 2010.

I used c++11 *auto* in my project, there is a line *CONFIG += c++11* in the *pro* file.

```
for(auto e : mapTerm->keys())
{
     mapTerm->insert(e, attrib.value(e).toString());
}
```

Now it cannot recognize the *auto* loop and gives me syntax errors.

Comment: MSVC 2010 is to old for c++11.

Comment: What is the auto loop? Some code would be nice...

Comment: You can use later Visual C++ versions (including Visual C++ 2015) with Windows XP by selecting the XP-compatible toolset in the project settings. Alternatively you can use the Visual C++ 2010 non-standard range based loop (the syntax is a little bit different as I recall), but I don't think there was any alternative to `auto`. So you'd have to spell out the type, or use the Visual ++ non-standard alternative to `decltype`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that you are using the propper C++ compiler and that it is C++11+.

If you are using msvc and are using the correct version then this should be a built in feature.